# Can I save the output images of TensorFlow Objectdetection API in a folder?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am new to object detection.
Can I save the output images of my tensorflow object detection API in a folder after detection is completed in the Jupyter notebook?

It was intuitive to right click and save the images when detecting a few images, but it is impractical to do same when I have over 1000 images to run detection on.

is the output already stored in a subfolder that I am unaware of??
Can I store the output in a folder or directory?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
I have checked differnt means but found nothing helpful

this is what my detection cell looks like [image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PIL you can save your image to disk. First you import the module

```
from PIL import Image
```

And then you can comment out the plot lines, add the save lines.

```
#plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
#plt.imshow(image_np)
#save to same folder as data input
img = Image.fromarray(image_np)
img.save(image_path[:-4]+'output_'+'.png')
```

Comment: Thanks @danyfang sadly, I'm still getting an error
ValueError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
---> 36       img.save(save_path)

/home/v/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.pyc in save(self, fp, format, **params)
   1987                 format = EXTENSION[ext]
   1988             except KeyError:
-> 1989                 raise ValueError('unknown file extension: {}'.format(ext))
   1990 
   1991         if format.upper() not in SAVE:
ValueError: unknown file extension:'

Comment: I've updated the code and you can retry my solution.

Comment: Thanks @danyfang for your prompt response. The extension error is gone but I am unable to see my output..... where is the new path they are stored since I am not pointing it to a directory of my choice. Thanks again. PS: I am using the github repository tensorflow/object_deteciton: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection.

Comment: The output is saved at the same path as input images, with added 'output_'

Comment: It is under `../models/research/object_detection/test_images/`